# Immutable.js conditionally update Map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

```
const state = fromJS({
  poolName: {
    poolNameCost:
    poolNamePercentage:
    poolNameShare:
  }
})
```

where `poolName` varies across actions.

I have to update all the properties `poolNameCost, poolNamePercentage, poolNameShare` if either of it updates.

I do

```
const { poolName, val, fieldSuffix, initialCost, initialShare } = action.payload;
state.update(`${poolName}`,
  items => ({
    ...items,
    [`${poolName}Cost`]() {
      if (suffix === 'Share') return (val / initialCost) * initialShare;
      if (suffix === 'Percentage') return (val / initialCost) * 100;
      return val
    },
    [`${poolName}Share`]() { //.....// },
    [`${poolName}Percentage`]() { //.....// },
  })
)
```

I get an empty object `poolName = {}`. Why does this happen?

The code above is a refactored version of the code below, that works well.

Code,

```
 (suffix === 'Cost') &&
 state.update(`${poolName}`,
  items => ({
    ...items,
    [`${poolName}Share`]: (val / initialCost) * initialShare,
    //...similarly for other sibling property of `Share` in `poolName`...//
  })
 )
```

values correctly update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines

```
[`${poolName}Cost`]() {
      if (suffix === 'Share') return (val / initialCost) * initialShare;
      if (suffix === 'Percentage') return (val / initialCost) * 100;
      return val
},
```

in code when invoked returned the functions themselve. So I changed them into IIFE, like this

```
[`${poolName}Cost`]: (function() {
      if (suffix === 'Share') return (val / initialCost) * initialShare;
      if (suffix === 'Percentage') return (val / initialCost) * 100;
      return val
})(),
```

Now it returns the underlying value after evaluation.

Is there a better way to achieve the result?